# BlackJack in Java with same Deck(s) for Dealer-Player

Tags: java, object, blackjack

I am writing a program in Java that is a classic BlackJack Game.

The rules are the same,and we make choices as players and the dealer(CPU) plays under some rules.

My code, that is beneath, makes 2 seperate stacks of Deck(s),one for Player and one for Dealer and each one draws from a different Deck but i want to make them both(Player and Dealer) draw from the same Deck(s).

Any suggestions/corrections on my Code ?

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class River 
{

    private int CardNumber;

    private int BeginCards;

    private int Decks;

    private int[] PartialSumArray = {4,8,12,16,20,24,28,32,36,52}; 

    private int[] BeginPartialSumArray = {4,8,12,16,20,24,28,32,36,52};

    private int PickedCard;

    private Random randomGenerator = new Random();

    //Constructor without definition
    public River()
    {
        CardNumber = 52;
        BeginCards = 52;
    }

    //Constructor with definition
    public River(int Decks)
    {
        CardNumber = Decks * 52;

        BeginCards = CardNumber;
        this.Decks = Decks; 

        //Initialize partial sum array for many decks of cards
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
            PartialSumArray[i] = PartialSumArray[i] * Decks;
            BeginPartialSumArray[i] = PartialSumArray[i] * Decks;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    //Create random numbers
    private int computeRandomSteps(int CardNumber)
    {
        //System.out.print("stin random , cardnumber is" + CardNumber);
        int randomSteps = randomGenerator.nextInt(CardNumber-1);
        return randomSteps;
    }


    public int nextCard()
    {

        int steps = computeRandomSteps(CardNumber);
        int position=0;

        for (int i=0; i<CardNumber; i++)
        {
            if (steps<= PartialSumArray[i])
            {
                position = i+1;
                break;
            }
        }

        CardNumber--;
        return position;
    }


    public int start()
    {
        int ShuffleLimit;
        PickedCard = nextCard();
        System.out.println("Picked card is :" + PickedCard);

        int HelpVariable = PickedCard-1;

        for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
            if (i >= HelpVariable)
            {
                PartialSumArray[HelpVariable] = PartialSumArray[i]-1;
                HelpVariable++;
            }
        }


        ShuffleLimit = BeginCards/4; 

        if (CardNumber<ShuffleLimit)
        {
            for (int i=0; i<9; i++)
            {
                BeginPartialSumArray[i] = BeginPartialSumArray[i] * Decks;
            }
        }
        return PickedCard;
    }


    public int ReturnCardNumber()
    {
        System.out.println("return cardnumber is " + CardNumber);
        return CardNumber;
    }

}



class Hand
{

    private int points;
    private int SumPoints=0;
    private boolean Ace = true;


    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    //Scanner input3 = new Scanner(System.in);

    //int Decks = input3.nextInt();

    River myRiver = new River();
    //River myRiver = new River(Decks);



    public int getPoints()
    {
        points = myRiver.start();
        if (points == 1 && Ace)
        {
            System.out.println("It is an Ace. Do you want to count 1 or 11?");

            points = input.nextInt();
            Ace = false;
        }
        SumPoints += points;
        System.out.println("Points are : " + SumPoints);
        return SumPoints;
    }

    public int getPointsDealer()
    {
        points = myRiver.start();
        if (points == 1 && Ace)
        {
            if (SumPoints + 11 > 21)
            {
                points = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                points = 11;
            }
            Ace = false;
        }
        SumPoints += points;
        System.out.println("Points are : " + SumPoints);
        return SumPoints;
    }
}


class Player
{
    private int points;
    private double account=0;
    private double bet;
    private boolean WinOrLose;

    Scanner input1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);

    public double placeBet()
    {
        System.out.println("How much do you want to bet?");
        bet = input1.nextDouble();

        return bet;
    }

    public double profit(boolean WinOrLose)
    {
        if (WinOrLose)
        {
            account += bet;
            return account;
        }
        else
        {
            account -= bet;
            return account;
        }
    }


    public int play(River other)
    {

        Hand myHand = new Hand();
        bet = placeBet();
        points = myHand.getPoints();
        boolean end = true;
        String Choice;

        while (end)
        {
            System.out.println("Make a choice");
            Choice = input2.nextLine();


            switch(Choice)
            {
            case "DoubleBet":
                bet = bet *2;
                points = myHand.getPoints();

                if (points > 21)
                {
                    System.out.print("Burned!");
                    WinOrLose = false;
                    account = profit(WinOrLose);
                    end = false;
                    break;
                }
                else if (points == 21)
                {
                    System.out.print("You won!");
                    WinOrLose = true;
                    account = profit(WinOrLose);
                    end = false;
                    break;
                }
                else 
                {
                    System.out.println("Your points are :" + points);
                    end = false;
                    break;
                }

            case "stop":
                System.out.println("Your points are :" + points);
                end = false;
                break;

            case "Hit":
                points = myHand.getPoints();
                if (points > 21)
                {
                    System.out.print("Burned!");
                    WinOrLose = false;
                    account = profit(WinOrLose);
                    end = false;
                    break;
                }
                else if (points == 21)
                {
                    System.out.print("You won!");
                    WinOrLose = true;
                    account = profit(WinOrLose);
                    end = false;
                    break;
                }
                break;

            default:
                System.out.println("That is not a choice.");
                end = false;
                break;
            }

        }
        return points;
    }
}

class BlackJack
{

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int SumPointsPlayer;
        int SumPointsDealer;
        boolean WinOrLose = true;
        double account;
        int Decks;
        int BeginCards;
        int ThisMomentCards;

        Scanner input1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("How many decks do you want to begin with?");
        Decks = input1.nextInt();


        River myRiver = new River(Decks);
        Player myPlayer = new Player();

        //Calculate the cards we have when the game starts
        BeginCards = 52 * Decks;

        System.out.println("Do you want to start the game? Yes or No.");
        String Repeat;

        Repeat = input2.nextLine();

        while (Repeat.equals("Yes"))
        {
            ThisMomentCards = myRiver.ReturnCardNumber();
            System.out.println("Cards are : " + ThisMomentCards);

            //Player's points for 1 round
            SumPointsPlayer = myPlayer.play(myRiver);

            //If player catches 21 he wins instantly
            if(SumPointsPlayer == 21)
            {
                account = myPlayer.profit(WinOrLose);
                System.out.println("Your account has :" + account + "dollars!");
            }
            //If player catches >21 he loses instantly
            else if(SumPointsPlayer > 21)
            {
                WinOrLose = false;
                account = myPlayer.profit(WinOrLose);
                System.out.println("Your account has :" + account + "dollars!");
            }
            //Compare the hand of player and dealer and the bigger wins
            else
            {
                //Dealer's points for 1 round
                SumPointsDealer = playDealer(myRiver);

                //If dealer catches >21 he loses instantly
                if(SumPointsDealer>21)
                {
                    System.out.println("Player wins!");
                    account = myPlayer.profit(WinOrLose);
                    System.out.println("Your account has :" + account + "dollars!");
                }
                //Hand of player bigger than the hand of the dealer , player wins
                else if (SumPointsPlayer>SumPointsDealer)
                {
                    WinOrLose = true;
                    account = myPlayer.profit(WinOrLose);
                    System.out.println("Player wins. Your account has :" + account + "dollars!");

                }
                //Hand of player smaller than the hand of the dealer , dealer wins
                else if (SumPointsPlayer<SumPointsDealer)
                {
                    WinOrLose = false;
                    account = myPlayer.profit(WinOrLose);
                    System.out.println("Player lost. Your account has :" + account + "dollars!");
                }
                //Hand of player is equal with the hand of the dealer , it is tie
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("Player and Dealer are tie!!");
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Do you want to continue the game? Yes or No.");
            Repeat = input2.nextLine();
        }

    }

    public static int playDealer(River other)
    {
        boolean bountry = true;

        System.out.println("Dealer plays :");

        Hand myHand = new Hand();
        int SumPointsDealer = myHand.getPointsDealer();

        while (bountry)
        {
            if (SumPointsDealer<17)
            {
                SumPointsDealer = myHand.getPointsDealer();
            }
            else if (SumPointsDealer>21)
            {
                System.out.println("Dealer burned!");
                bountry = false;
            }
            else
            {
                bountry = false;
            }
        }
        return SumPointsDealer;
    }
}
```

Some Clarifications:

1) The way we draw randomly a card is based on a strange way but this is not the problem its ok the way the program Does draw randomly cards from the Decks

2) Another problem that i noticed is that in class Hand the code that i have in // is not working as it doesnt allow me to have a System.out.println()

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    //Scanner input3 = new Scanner(System.in);

    //int Decks = input3.nextInt();

    River myRiver = new River();
    //River myRiver = new River(Decks);
```

I wanted to do this so that i will say with how many Decks the user wants to play

Comment: SO is not right place for code reviews. Look here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can do better and easier of code is oriented into objects.
i.e.  Collections.shuffle(Deck) replaces that whole random conundrum
where Deck is your created Object made of such attributes as LinkedList and a counter[deck value]
hope that helps.

remove object Card from linked list of main deck and move it into the deck of a player. and yes, you can create as many decks as you want that way.

object Card has attributes Value and Suit.